# Preciso informar para o usuario se contem um usuario cadastrado com este mesmo nome de usuario

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Opa, então, eu preciso informar para quem estiver utilizando o programa, se ja tem algum usuário cadastrado com este nome e informar a idade do mesmo contem na lista cujo deve ser cadastrado antes da verificação, porem estou tendo algumas dificuldades com isso, principalmente na questão de buscar esses dados e imprimir, segue código.

````
opções1 = ("1 - Cadastrar novo usuário")
opções2 = ("2 - Listar usuários cadastrados")
opções3 = ("3 - Sair do sistema")
opções4 = ("4 - Busca de usuarios")
escolha = 0
CadastroUsuario = 0
Usuarios = list()
Idade = list()
separador= list()
lista = ""
valor = 0


while escolha != 4:

    print(opções)
    print(opções1)
    print(opções2)
    print(opções3)
    print(opções4)

    escolha = int(input("Qual opção deseja fazer? "))

    print(escolha)

    if escolha == 1:

        CadastroUsuario = int(input("Deseja cadastrar quantas pessoas? "))

        if CadastroUsuario <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor Inválido! Digite inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')

        for c in range(1, CadastroUsuario + 1):
            Usuarios.append(input(f"Digite o nome do {c} Usuario: "))
            Idade.append(input(f"Digite a idade do {c} Usuario: "))
            separador.append(print(f"\033[1;34m=-==-==-==-= FIM DE CADASTRO DO USUARIO {c}!! =-==-==-==-=\033[m"))
            print(f'{c}')

    if escolha == 2:
        if CadastroUsuario > 0:
            print(f'0s usuários são: \033[32m{Usuarios}\033[m')
            print(f'As idades são: \033[32m{Idade}\033[m')

        elif CadastroUsuario == 0:
            print('=-=' * 10)
            print(f"\033[1;34mNão temos nenhum usuario cadastrado, para cadastrar um usuário, digite 1!!\033[m")

    if escolha == 3:
        print("Finalizando...")

    elif escolha == 4:

        procurar = input("Digite quem você procura: ")

        print('Usuario cadastrado? {}'.format(procurar in Usuarios))

        def search (usuarios, valor):
            return [(Usuarios.index(x), x.index(valor)) for x in Usuarios if valor in x]

        for i in Usuarios:
            local = Usuarios.index(i)
            for b in i:
                if b == procurar:         
                    print("teste: [{}]".format(local))
                    break

        print("Quem você procura:",lista[local])
        
    elif escolha > 4:
        print(f"\033[1;31mOpção inválida. Tente novamente\033[m")


    elif escolha <= 0:
        print(f"\033[1;31mOpção inválida. Tente novamente\033[m")

    print('=-=' * 10)
print(f"\033[1;32mVocê saiu do programa com exito!! volte sempre!\033[m") ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No python existe o operador "in", ele retorna um valor booleano (True ou False), caso algum valor existe em uma variável composta (Lista, tuplas, até strings).

A que você pode fazer é não adicionar o valor do nome do usuário diretamente na sua lista como você fez, e sim armazenar antes em uma variável e adicionar na lista apenas se não existir um valor igual dentro da lista, e usar a função index, que retorna a posição de um valor dentro de uma lista para exibir os dados já cadastrados.

```
lista_nome = ['João', 'Matheus', 'Maria']
lista_idade = [18, 35, 76]
nome = str(input('Nome: '))
idade = int(input('Idade: ')

if name in lista:
    print(f'{lista_nome[lista_nome.index(name)]} já está cadastrado e tem {lista_idade[lista_nome.index(name)]} anos')
else:
    lista_nome.append(nome)
    lista_idade.append(idade)
```

A lógica é simples, se o nome já existir na lista de nomes ele mostra as informações, printa o nome usando como posição para a lista a função index nela mesmo para achar o nome, e do mesmo jeito na lista de idades para achar a idade correspondente, e se não existir, o adiciona.

> você pode usar o "not" também, que em python inverte o valor,
> basicamente um "não" mesmo, a lógica ficaria como "if name not in
> lista_nome", que seria "se o nome não estiver na lista_nome", nesse caso > você inverteria as condições, se o nome não existir na lista você o
> adiciona

Espero que tenha entendido!